# Absolutely Positioned Elements Do Not Animate with Jquery SlideToggle in ie7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a hidden section in my HTML that is shown and hidden on button press using JQuery's 'slideToggle' function.

This button is below the hidden content and animates happily with all browsers but ie7, is there a way to force it to animate without having to rewrite the button so that it's not positioned absolutely?

```
<div class="hiddenContent">
<p>Hidden content is in here</p>
</div>
<div class="showmorecontainer">
<a class="showmore" href="#">SHOW</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

I've added some CSS and JQuery for context (note the HTML above was simplified)

CSS -
    .showmorecontainer{
    height:24px;
    }

```
.showmore{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:22px;
background-image:url('../images/showmore.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:330px;
display:block;
padding-left:195px;
padding-top:2px;
}
```

JQuery -

```
$(".showmore").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.hiddenContent').slideToggle('slow',      function() {
        if($(this).is(":hidden")){
            $(this).parent().find('.showmore').html('SHOW ME MORE');
            $(this).parent().find('.arrow').removeClass('arrowup');
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().find('.showmore').html('CLOSE BACK UP');
            $(this).parent().find('.arrow').addClass('arrowup');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Could we see some javascript and css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just seems to be an issue with CSS in IE7.  Absolutely positioned elements do not animate but jump to the end point.  I solved this by just getting rid of the absolute positioning and using negative margins instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether IE7 is throwing any errors but if it is, you might want to examine them closer.  I don't have access to IE7 at the moment to test this but I'm wondering if changing this line of code...

`$(this).parent().parent().find('.hiddenContent').slideToggle('slow',      function() {`

...to this...

`$(this).parents().find('.hiddenContent').slideToggle('slow',      function() {`

...might help.

Comment: Thank you for trying, there were no errors in the JQuery however it just seems to be an IE7 CSS issue, I solved it by removing the absolute positioning, and using negative margins instead